# Rails Return Results Closest to Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a method to return one set of results if it is Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday. That part works fine, it's the `else` I can't work out.

What I want it to return is the results closest to `Date.today` compared to the `date` column on my data model.

But currently it returns results from the week before and adding `+ 1.week` or `+ 7.days` to my query did nothing.

```
def method
  if Date.today.tuesday? || Date.today.wednesday? Date.today.thursday?
    @foobar = @foobar.where(completed: :false).limit(4)
  else
    @foobar = @foobar.where('date > ?', Date.today).limit(4)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have an `order` scope on your query, so Rails is not sorting by date. From your `else`, it looks like you want to retrieve the 4 closest `Foobars` greater than todays date.

So give `@foobar.where('date > ?', Date.today).order(date: :asc).limit(4)` a try.

Comment: As always, I have overlooked the glaringly obvious answer!

Thanks @chrismanderson